# Error in source(x, encoding = "UTF-8") in r

Tags: r, sapply

I have to run a piece of code to list the files in the directory using the source function, but it is throwing an error. Please help me solve this. This is the code

```
invisible(sapply(list.files("./Src/LibrariesAndFunctions/",full.names = TRUE,recursive = TRUE),
       function(x) {
         source(x,encoding = "UTF-8")
       }))
```

This is the code for I103_Setup.R

```
##
##  xyz_Setup.R
##
##    source("./Src/xyz_Setup.R")
##

options(encoding = "UTF-8")

if (!exists("xyz.setup.loaded") || xyz.setup.loaded == FALSE) {

  xyz.setup.loaded <<- TRUE

  ##
  ## (Log files) # Actually this is in Japanese
  ##    DEBUG
  ##    INFO
  ##    ERROR
  ##
  logging.levels <<- c("DEBUG", "INFO", "ERROR")
  logging.currentLevel <<- "INFO"

  ##
  ##
  ##
  logging.file <<- "xyz.log"

}
```

I'm getting the error

```
 Error in source(x, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  ./Src/LibrariesAndFunctions//01_Setup_Logging_Milestone/I103_Setup.R:15:0: unexpected end of input
13:   ##
14:   ## 
   ^
```

I think the error is throwing up because it is unable to parse other languages. Is there a way to parse languages other than English in R? Essentially UTF-8 encoding should take care of this problem. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Hard to know from the information you've provided. Could you share the code in I103_Setup.R? Probably missing a bracket or something on line 14 of the I103_Setup.R script.

Comment: ```##
##  XYZ_Setup.R
##
##    source("./Src/XYZ_Setup.R")
##

options(encoding = "UTF-8")

if (!exists("xyz.setup.loaded") || xyz.setup.loaded == FALSE) {
  
  xyz.setup.loaded <<- TRUE
  
  ##
  ## Log level
  ##    DEBUG
  ##    INFO
  ##    ERROR
  ##
  logging.levels <<- c("DEBUG", "INFO", "ERROR")
  logging.currentLevel <<- "INFO"
  
  ##
  ## 
  ##
  logging.file <<- "xyz.log"
  
}
``` This is the piece of I103_Setup.R @xilliam

Comment: Sorry, I could have been more precise. Could you post this as a code block, just like it appears in the I103_Setup.R script? It will be helpful to see what's happening at line 14. You could edit your original post.